# How to display a dynamic map in Power BI using Python script

Tags: python, powerbi

I'm trying to display a dynamic map in Power BI through Python script editor. This is my code in Python (**it works properly**):

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Read geojson
mapa = gpd.read_file('spain_map.json')
# Read xlsx
pedidos_venta = pd.read_excel("sale_orders.xlsx")
# Merge by the common column
mapa_pedidos_venta = mapa.merge(pedidos_venta, left_on='acom_name', right_on='acon_name_')

# Plot map 
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 6))
mapa_pedidos_venta.plot(ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

As I'm looking for getting a **dynamic map** in Power BI, **I've changed this code for Python script editor of Power BI using fields of my Power BI dataset**. This dataset has been imported merging
the two files mentioned above. I want to use three fields:

- acom_name: names of Spain regions.
- pedidos_venta: number of sale order by region
- geometry: coordenates of regions (imported of geojson file).

**Power BI automatically generates** the next dataframe:

```
dataset = pandas.DataFrame(geometry, pedidos_venta, acom_name)
```

And this is that I've tried:

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 6))
dataset.plot(ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

However, **I didn't get a map visualization**. This code now show me a line graph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, it's neccesary to drag your variables onto the map (in this case, acon_name and pedidos_venta). Then this code will work properly:

```
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Reading geojson
mapa = gpd.read_file('spain_map.json')

# Merging by the common column
mapa_pedidos_venta = mapa.merge(dataset, left_on='acom_name', right_on=dataset.acom_name)

# Drawing the map
mapa_pedidos_venta.plot(edgecolor='black', linewidth=1)

# Displaying the map
plt.show()
```

It's possible to format yout map with something like:

```
# Defining colors:
def color_range(row):
    if row['pedidos_venta'] > 3000:
        return '#00ff00'
    elif round(row['pedidos_venta'],4) >= 2000:
        return '#FFFF00'
    else:
        return '#FF0000'

# Asigning colors:
color_map = mapa_pedidos_venta.apply(asignar_color,axis=1)

#Changing figsize and dpi
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (50,25)
plt.rcParams['figure.dpi'] = 140

# Plotting the map
mapa_pedidos_venta.plot(color=color_map, edgecolor='black', linewidth=1)

#Adding labels
for idx, row in mapa_pedidos_venta.iterrows():
    etiqueta = '{:.2%}'.format(row['pedidos_venta'])
    plt.annotate(text=etiqueta, xy=row['geometry'].centroid.coords[0], ha='center', fontsize=40)

# Removing axes
plt.axis('off')

# Displaying the map
plt.show()
```